# Intellij Markdown Plugin preview bottom?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

How to make Intellij's Markdown plugin show the preview on the bottom of the page rather than on the right?

[image: Preview to the right]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah found it. It is in the Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Markdown:

[image: How to change the layout of the preview pane]